# Why didn't they hide BB-8 and disguise themselves when they went to talk to Maz Kanata?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

> They went there to ask Maz to bring them to Leia.

And it's like they were thinking like this:

> "Hey, the First Order is looking for us, but that's not a big deal, so let's just walk around and have some drinks."

Why? Why not hide the droid and use some disguises?

> And in the end, the First Order and the Resistance catch up with them, and General Leia ends up there. It just seems so much convenient. And I'm not even bringing up the fact that Luke's lightsaber was also there (which was also so much convenient).

Comment: I believe they technically recognized the droid and not them.  More specifically I believe they tracked their ship there making it a little silly to wear disguises.  There are a lot of issues like this in the movie.

Comment: That's true, I forgot they knew they could be tracked (I remember Han Solo stating that if it was easy for him to track the Falcon, it would be even easier for the First Order).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Han didn't think it mattered too much. Novelization says:

  > “Why are we here again?” he asked as they started up a wide, curving stone staircase.
  >
  > **“To get your droid on a clean ship. Do you think it was luck that Chewie and I found the Falcon? If we can find it on our scanners, the First Order’s not far behind.”**

  To me this sounds like in his opinion, the fact that BB-8 is here is already known to First Order anyway, so why waste time on disguises?

  Ironically, it seems he was wrong as First Order actually needed a spy to tell them that they arrived.

  > The communicator she employed was capable of sending encrypted messages via the central planetary communications booster. With that much power at her disposal, it did not take long to establish a long-range connection.
  >
  > “Yes. It’s Bazine Netal. I’ve got them.”
- In addition, he sort of counted on the anonymity of a busy cantina - **he was kind of used to that, if you recall the original scene in cantina on Tatooine**, where everyone was minding their own business even among shootouts.

  > Gently but firmly taking the blaster he had given her out of Rey’s hands, Han pointedly holstered it for her at the back of her belt. “Not an establishment to walk into holding a gun. First impressions are important.
  >
  > “**The most important thing here is to keep a low profile, stay under the radar**. Maz is a bit of an acquired taste. So let me do the talking. And whatever you do, don’t stare.”

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

- They (well, Han) knew that the Falcon was trackable. If Han and Chewie could find it, then so could Kylo Ren/The First Order. (The only reason Han & Chewie couldn't find it before was because it was sitting in a junkyard, completely deactivated.) So it was just a matter of time before their enemies caught up to them; they needed to rely on speed, not secrecy.
- They were going to Maz Kanata to ask a favor. It would have been ... counterproductive, not to mention impolite, to start out by attempting subterfuge, since Maz was famous for her ability to see right through people.

I suppose they could have attempted to disguise just BB-8 (Maz could hardly be offended by that), but keep in mind that the droid was part of what enabled the resistance spy at the castle to recognize them, and send the message that eventually saved their collective butts. Of course, it's also what allowed the First Order spy to recognize them, which led to their butts being in need of saving... but then again, we've already established that the Falcon would have sooner or later brought the stormtroopers on them.

(As far as why they didn't disguise just the droid, I don't think they realized how distinctive BB-8 was, nor how much detail the First Order knew about the droid. Also, how do you disguise a BB unit? Pretty much anything you apply to it is liable to "gum up the works", innit?)

Comment: I think they could have let the driod in the ship, and han solo should have gone alone to talk to maz.

Comment: @Alessandro, perhaps Han wanted to be able to show Maz the map.

Comment: Han mentioned it even in the film explicitely that that is true about the falcon.  what is strange still is that the falcon was used in the last scene.....

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it would matter since Maz called out Han Solo the moment she recognized him. Something about her tells me she would have anyway even if they were under cloaks.

Comment: I think the main concern of the question isn't about disguising themselves from Maz, but from everyone else in the bar. They were going to trust Maz anyway - what about the rest of the clientele, who were the ones you turned them in?

Comment: I think I answered that concern pretty well. Maz did not wave them quietly to a corner, she called out Han Solo to the whole establishment which shushed in response.

Comment: @Escoce - that's the point of the objection. If Han disguised himself, and then quietly slided up to Maz and said "hey, it's me but keep it on down low, y'hear", she woudln't have announced it to the world.

Comment: @DVK: wouldn't she, though? She seems to be the type of cantankerous old lady who *would* have announced Han's presence, just to annoy him. :)

Comment: @Martha - her main concern is to help Leia and Rey. Doesn't seem like trolling is in her character

Comment: No one said she was trolling. Everyone in the galaxy knows Han Solo is wanted by half the criminals in the galaxy, she would most certainly know that, and yet.....HAN SOLO!!!!! (Bar goes silent)